# Rails SSL setup with Apache, Puma, Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, ssl, puma

I'm having trouble setting up my Rails application to successfully use SSL. The stack is using apache, puma and ubuntu. My app is running on port 3000.

Without SSL I had the app up and running great. Now, the only thing shown at the my URL is the `/var/www/myapp/public` directory listing. I just can't get my Rails app to show.

The app is successfully redirecting all `http` traffic to `https`.

Can anyone with a successful setup share their `sites-available` config files, or suggest changes to mine below? I have a feeling there is a single line somewhere I'm missing. This is my first time trying to get an SSL cert rails app server up and running.

I don't understand how my app running at port 3000 is supposed to show up when viewing the site via SSL on port 443.

Here is my `sites-available` setup:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin admin@<MYAPP.COM>
                ServerName <MYAPP.COM>

                DocumentRoot /var/www/<MYAPP>/public

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/<MYAPP.crt>
                SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/<MYAPP.key>

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Been banging my head against Google for the last 5 hours. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I’m not sure how you’re hosting this, but in the past, my team has used AWS, and we put the cert on the ELB. This leaves the traffic encrypted between the client and our ELB, and then everything internal uses HTTP so that we don’t have to install the certs on a ton of servers (we have redundancy) and don’t have to worry about making Rails (or Apache) deal with the cert.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure apache as a reverse proxy.

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```